# How to return a result per-image in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I'm using DropZone to upload a batch of images, but I would like to inform the user immediately  after each image on it's status.

e.g. if an image is not qualified then I would like to mark is as such.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Dropzone.js allows you to attach callbacks to many different [events](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_8). Start there and post here if you're having an issue with your implementation.

Comment: I know I can catch many events the question is how do I return from the server events on finished files while DropZone still uploads other files?

Comment: The `success` and `error` callbacks can be used for this. The `success` callback gets called when the file has been uploaded successfully. Gets the server response as second argument. The `error` callback get called when an error occured. Receives the errorMessage as second parameter and if the error was due to the XMLHttpRequest the xhr object as third. [Reference](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_8)

Comment: Do you get a notification on each file you upload when a batch of files is sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/247

> **enyo commented on Aug 1, 2013** If you have uploadMultiple set to true,
>   then one AJAX request should contain as many files as parallelUploads.
>   If you have uploadMultiple set to false then there will be as many
>   AJAX requests as parallelUploads. Pedro Cunha
>
> **pedrocunha commented on Aug 1, 2013** Exactly see this bug could be
>   considered a feature :) because I could set parallelUploads to 1 and
>   per AJAX request have only one image at time but several uploads at
>   same time Pedro Cunha
>
> **pedrocunha commented on Aug 1, 2013** My point being: this is very
>   important because if one image fails to upload for some reason, let's
>   say a server validation error, you can handle just that image. If you
>   are handling a collection of stuff it's trickier to show errors. Do
>   you understand I mean?
>   It looks like it would be nice to configure the amount of images sent
>   on each AJAX request ?

Meaning if I set:

```
{
  parallelUploads: 8,
  uploadMultiple: false,
}
```

Then it will upload 8 files in prallel each in its own AJAX call and the server can return deiffernt error code per-image.

Answer (score 2):

Dropzone.js allows you to attach callbacks to various [events](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_8) in the cycle. To provide a status after each file is uploaded to the server, you can register `success` and `error` callbacks to provide this functionality.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post" });

// attach callback to the `success` event
myDropzone.on("success", function( file, result ) {
  // the file parameter is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File
  // the result parameter is the result from the server

  // [success code here]
});

// attach callback to the 'error' event
myDropzone.on("error", function( file, errorMessage, xhr ) {
  // if the xhr parameter exists, it means the error was server-side

  if (xhr) {
    // [error code here]
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the question is how the server can send an event after each image when a batch is uploaded?